# How to add additional fields into a final JSON through accessors?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to add an empty collection that will always be. I do it.

```
protected $appends = ['additional'];

public function getAdditionalAttribute()
{
    return collect();
}
```

Then I do additional accessor, for example

```
public function getSomeAttributeAttribute()
{
    //some code
    return $something; //bool
}
```

Then in the right place I call this accessor `->append('some_attribute');`
But I need that the result was inside in the collection `additional`.
I try do it like this:

```
public function getSomeAttributeAttribute()
{
    //some code
    return $this->additional['some_attribute'] = $something; //bool
}
```

But it does not work, and the result is on the same level with all the elements, not inside of the collection `additional`.
I can do something like this:

```
public function getAdditionalAttribute()
{
    return collect([
        'some_attribute' => $this->some_attribute
    ]);
}
```

It works, but this value will be constantly, but I want to call it only when it is necessary through `->append('some_attribute');`
But the collection to be constantly although empty.
Or maybe there is a different way to make it. How can I do it?

Comment: please update the getting response and expecting in the question

Comment: change the `getAdditionalAttribute` and put it inside the collect

Comment: N69S, Yes, I can do something like this
`public function getAdditionalAttribute()
{
    return collect([
                   'some_attribute' => $this->some_attribute,
               ]);
}`
It works, but this value will be constantly, but I want to call it only when it is necessary through  `->append('some_attribute');`, But the collection to be constantly although empty . Can I do this?

Comment: you  can use something like mapping in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map
The map method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items

Comment: You're using an accessor as a mutator when doing `$this->additional['some_attribute'] = $something;`. And why do you need to call `->append('some_attribute');` in the right place if you already define `protected $appends = ['additional'];`?

Comment: I need to have a collection `additional` always, even empty.  But in the right place (not always) I need to call `->append('some_attribute');`, and so the result got into this collection.

Comment: Why do you need a collection when it just has to have zero to one keys? That sounds like a model to me at best

Comment: Maybe a model, I am not sure. The idea is that after serialization in JSON to the frontend comes among other things, the "Additional" section, which is constant. And then in the controller where we need to call a mutator like `->append('some_attribute')`, and its value fell into this section.  There may be several such attributes over time, and the idea is in that as it is to group them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier for you to overwrite the serialization itself:

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Convert the object into something JSON serializable.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'additional' => [
                'some_attribute' => $something
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

---

If you need the collection, you may want to use a [custom one](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#custom-collections) (`php artisan make:collection \\App\\Collections\\AdditionalCollection`):

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    public function getAdditionalAttribute()
    {
        return new App\Collections\AdditionalCollection($something);
    }
}
```

```php
class AdditionalCollection extends Collection
{
    private $something;

    public function __construct($something)
    {
        $this->something = $something;

        parent::__construct([]);
    }

    public function __get(string $property)
    {
        if ($property === 'some_attribute') {
            return $this->something;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this way does not fits.

Comment: I do not solve such questions. Even if it turns out to be configured as it should, the standard methods cannot be touched.

Comment: Since JSON is just a string, there won't be any collection methods either way.